# capture errors from SQL Server in a PHP application using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server

Prior to using PDO the following code worked well for making SQL Server error messages visible in PHP:

```
/* Connect to the local server using Windows Authentication and 
specify the AdventureWorks database as the database in use. */
$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Set up a query to select an invalid column name. */
$tsql = "SELECT InvalidColumnName FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail";

/* Attempt execution. */
/* Execution will fail because of the invalid column name. */
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
      if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null)
      {
         foreach( $errors as $error)
         {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."\n";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."\n";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."\n";
         }
      }
}
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($errors,1) . "</pre>";
/* Free connection resources */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Note: the code above originally came from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296200%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Now I'm using PDO and would like something similar to use with that.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the question really just, "how do I catch errors with PDO"?

Comment: The question is how do I catch errors generated by the database with PDO.

Comment: You would need to convert this entire query to PDO to be able to do that..

Comment: You should post the actual code you are using, not the previous version that worked well.

Comment: I have no code to post for the PDO version.  Thus the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the whole class I use, which I took from the [php-login.net project](http://php-login.net) and changed only 1 thing. When there is an error, the whole thing dies and whines about it. Maybe it is what you need:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Database
 * Creates a PDO database connection. This connection will be passed into the models (so we use
 * the same connection for all models and prevent to open multiple connections at once)
 */
class Database extends PDO
{
    /**
     * Construct this Database object, extending the PDO object
     * By the way, the PDO object is built into PHP by default
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        /**
         * set the (optional) options of the PDO connection. in this case, we set the fetch mode to
         * "numbers", which means all results will be by number column, like this: $result[0] !
         * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
         */
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        /**
         * Generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
         * @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
         * Also important: We include the charset, as leaving it out seems to be a security issue:
         * @see http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Connecting_to_MySQL says:
         * "Adding the charset to the DSN is very important for security reasons,
         * most examples you'll see around leave it out. MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CHARSET!"
         */
        parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another useful resource: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/04/20/comparing-the-sqlsrv-and-pdo-apis.aspx